# Error 404 with TypeScript / ES6 Module System

Tags: typescript, es6-modules

I get an error 404 (in browser dev tools) when I try to access the member exported from one typescript module into other module

```
<body>

  <script src="./scripts/script1.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="./scripts/script2.js" type="module"></script>

</body>
```

Inside file: script1.ts

```
export let myName: string = "Saad Ali";
```

Inside file: script2.ts

```
import { myName } from "./script1";

console.log(myName)
```

Comment: Es module specifiers require [extensions](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#mandatory-file-extensions).

Comment: You should share your project. Because it sounds like a bundle or typescript config issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I've found the solution. The reason I was getting an error has nothing to do with the compiler configuration given that I was using **ES6 for modules** and **target as ES2016.**

I wanted to make this all work for the browser without the any help of module bundlers or extra libs/extensions.

**What was the problem then?**
The output that tsc compiler was generating for me wasn't including the file extensions for the JavaScript files and by just adding .js extensions to the omitted files, it all worked.

Don't forget adding **type="module"** when referencing to script files in your html file.